# Select only one item in ListView

Tags: android

I have a ListView with a custom BaseAdapter that renders the bus number, origin and destination. When a row is clicked, I want the origin and destination to disappear and show two buttons. I have that done through clicklisteners on the adapter, but I need it to show the two buttons onle on one item at a time (hiding them when a different row is selected).

This is much like the Twitter application for Android. I have tried to do this using a MultiChoiceModeListener, although I feel like it is not what I'm looking for.

This is the code for the clickListener on the getView() method of the adapter

```
busLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) (v.getParent());
            parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_selector).setVisibility(View.GONE);
            parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_description).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
```

XML file of the layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bus_label"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/busline_height"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/busline_width">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_number"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/regularbusfg"
            android:background="@color/regularbusbg"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bus_description"
        android:visibility="visible"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_origin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_destination"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/bus_selector"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:textColor="@color/darkgreyfg"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_going"
            android:text="@string/going"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#DBDBDB"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bus_coming"
            android:text="@string/coming"
            android:textAllCaps="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:gravity="center" />

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

I come from web development and all I needed before was to look for the element with the class selected, remove it and apply the class to the new element. What is the procedure to get this behavior on Android? There should be a standard or "most accepted" way of doing this.

Comment: Can you post the code to your clickListener?  Also, is it working at all now?  for example, are the buttons showing and just not hiding the other row's buttons?

Comment: please post the code with xml file.

Comment: Can't you iterate through the list and insure all are hidden before showing the new one? ...or just make a reference to the previously selected elements and hide them on new one selection.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simplest thing that you can do is to save the last `View` that the user clicked on, and if the user click on another item, you can change the visibility of the last view that you saved.

```
busLabel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             if (mLastView != null)
                 deselect(mLastView);
             select(v);
             mLastView = v;
        }
    });

private void select(View v) {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) (v.getParent());
    parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_selector).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_description).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

private void deselect(View v) {
    LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) (v.getParent());
    parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_selector).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    parent.findViewById(R.id.bus_description).setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm, Thanks :) saved lots of hours